# Sum values from one table depending on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let's say that I have two tables:

First table: Accounts table

| Accountname | accountCode |
| --- | --- |
| Client1 | 11 |
| Client2 | 111 |
| Client3 | 112 |

Second Table: Account Details

| AccountCode | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 500 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 200 |
| 111 | 700 | 0 |
| 112 | 300 | 0 |
| 112 | 0 | 400 |

I need to make a query that results the next table :

| AccountName | TotalDebit | TotalCredit | CumulativeBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | 500 | 200 | 300 |
| Client2 | 700 | 0 | 1000 |
| Client3 | 300 | 400 | 900 |

I have tried this, but it shows only the AccountCode:

```
select
    sum(Debit) as TotalDebit,
    sum(Credit) as TotalCredit,
    Account_Code as AC
from AccountDetails as A 
inner join Accounts as B ON A.AccountCode = B.AccountCode
where AccountCode like N'11%'
group by A.AccountCode
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Its not possible for your query to only return the account name. It must also be showing a total debit and total credit. Maybe you are looking for help to get the cum balance?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I will Edit the qusetion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select   accountname
        ,sum(debit)                                                                      as total_debit
        ,sum(credit)                                                                     as total_credit
        ,sum(coalesce(sum(debit),0)-coalesce(sum(credit),0)) over(order by accountname)  as cumulative_balance 

from     accounts a join account_details ad on ad.accountcode = a.accountcode
group by accountname
```

| accountname | total_debit | total_credit | cumulative_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | 500 | 200 | 300 |
| client2 | 700 | null | 1000 |
| client3 | 300 | 400 | 900 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zywJkHTX)